# Cannot change the WSL2 network switch connection type

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 as my WSL distribution, and I've been trying to connect a Wi-Fi adapter to it. I searched the web and found that I need use the Hyper-V manager to change the WSL switch connection type from 'internal' to 'external' and then select my adapter.

But every time I do this, WSL loses connection to the Internet, and it does not change the IP address to a LAN one. In addition every time I restart the PC, the connection type is reset back to Internal.

Any idea how to fix?

Comment: I'll be honest -- I answer a lot of WSL questions, but I typically leave my network configuration with the "defaults" for the most part since WSL2 is a bit weak in this area.  Can you provide some more information on what you are trying to do by connecting a Wi-Fi adapter?  Are you trying to create a network just for the WSL2 distribution that is separate from the Windows one?  Or something else?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds, no. I'm using wsl because I like bash way more then the powershell or cmd type of terminal. I'm a cyber security student, and I'm currently learning about networking. Recently I built a network scanner in python, and when I ran it from the wsl terminal I fount out that the ip address of the wsl is not related to the LAN ones. And the host is unreachable from other devices from the Lan. That's why I'm trying to connect the wifi adapter, so the wsl will be a part of the Lan.